# can Thruway PubSub allow amend message before publish?

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet, thruway

chat application example.

> Mr A (07-Aug-2017 15:01) : hello all
>   Mr B (07-Aug-2017 15:20) : hello Mr A

The Server Date Time (dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm) is inserted by Server. Which I can easy done in Ratchet.
[Ratchet.Wamp.WampServerInterface api document](http://socketo.me/api/class-Ratchet.Wamp.WampServerInterface.html#_onPublish)
Inside the OnPublish, Where I can amend the message before really publish out.

Can Thruway do the same ? I cannot find any Thruway doc, and I see the examples but not found what I want.[Thruway Examples](https://github.com/voryx/Thruway/tree/master/Examples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if I needed to accomplish this, I would use a slightly different architecture. I believe the idea of WAMP is to keep the router very generic. That is why we don't have any examples of this.

“All application specific code should reside in WAMP application components, not in the router itself.”
—tobias

That being said, it still would not be too difficult to do what you want to do - but would require intercepting the messages. Ideally, it would be nice to override the Broker - but we don't have a generic way to switch that out right now. So we can override the Router and inspect every message:

```
class MyRouter extends Router {
    public function onMessage(TransportInterface $transport, Message $msg) {
        if ($msg instanceof PublishMessage) {
            if ($msg->getTopicName() == "mytopic") {
                // mangle the message in here
            }
        }

        parent::onMessage($transport, $msg);
    }
}
```

Then just use this class instead of the default Router when you are starting up.

I have not tried this code, if I get a chance I will. The idea should work though.

Comment: Yep, as Matt mentions, a WAMP Router should not contain application specific code, since this breaks the fundamental design of WAMP. That being said, having a router add timestamps to published events (when configured to do so) would be possible - but _not_ in the event's application payload, but in the `details` field of the WAMP `EVENT` message (https://github.com/tavendo/WAMP/blob/master/spec/basic.md#event). This could then be accessed in a subscriber. Having "event timestamping" would be general enough to justify such addition.

Comment: If there is interest in "event timestamping", we should first describe it in WAMP advanced profile (after adding an issue on the WAMP repo), and then WAMP router implementations can opt to implement that feature. It's exactly for this kind of stuff that we designed WAMP2 to be extensible: we have that `EVENT.details|dict` where we can put extra stuff without breaking things. Clients that don't understand a field in the `details` dict simply will ignore it - or even simpler: forward the full `details` to the app code.

Comment: Thanks Matt and oberstet. Oic, I understand now. So the right way to get the "standard" time, should not from WAMP Router, I can create a "getStandardTime" RPC instead, which in a running Thurway client. call it only before client prepare the message to publish , is it better?

Comment: Finally, I understood. The PubSub should 100% keep "what subscriber see is what publisher give". My intention to breaking things is wrong. thanks.

Comment: @VirtualJasper Of course you could have a `getStandardTime` procedure in a backend application component. A publisher of an event could call that procedure, insert the time into the app payload of the event, and only publish then. That is possible today, with no changes whatsoever. However, a publisher then can "fake" the time (by not calling the `getStandardTime`). With "event timestamping" as above, nothing can be faked (as long as you trust the Router - which is inevitable anyway). A subscriber can be _sure_ the time is correct. If you trust your publishers, then it's a non-issue.

Comment: @oberstet your comment is right. use the example of chat application again, except 'standtime' i have other idea to insert into the publish message or some control. for example like icq/msn/yahoo messenger, each user have ignore list, if using the PubSub to control message, is it possible? what i try to do is insert the application code to 1.query the database for the ignore list. 2.if sender match ignore list, don't publish, else publish it. .......

Comment: will it break the rule of “All application specific code should reside in WAMP application components, not in the router itself.”  Is  running application code in RPC is better choice, call RPC to send message instead of using the PubSub, since PubSub is not design to do it? PubSub is used to be a honest mail man, take and send.

Comment: @VirtualJasper If you want to have more control over what goes into a published event, you can do this: instead of a frontend client directly publishing, make it call into a backend procedure. Inside this proc (which runs in an app component by you), you can do any kind of validation and enrichment. Then have _that_ proc do the publish. Revoke direct publication rights from frontend client (only the proc. is allowed to be called). Allow the backend proc. component to publish instead. This is a pattern we sometimes use, it's very flexible and it does not break "Router should not run app code".